# Is there any software that tags movie metadata automatically?

Tags: video, tv, metadata, tags

I'm familiar with using MusicBrainz for MP3s. Is there an equivalent program that exists for video files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Doesn't look like it**, there's a few [unanswered](http://www.mac-forums.com/forums/movies-video/199429-movie-tag-software.html) forum posts scattered all over the place. My guess would be because of the size of the movie it's not possible to come up with an efficient signature to do a quick lookup on, which isn't the case with 3-4 minute songs.

Have a look at how the music identifier service like ['Audio Fingerprinting' in MusicBrainz](http://wiki.musicbrainz.org/Audio_Fingerprint) and [Shazam](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shazam_%28service%29#Implementations) work, for some insight into why this **would be difficult for movies**.

It's probably going to be a manual process, but there's some other tools.

---

Have a look at some lists that talk about extending Media center extensions and other apps that might help your manual process work better, in terms of getting other supporting info.

**Windows**

> http://lifehacker.com/212345/8-killer-windows-media-center-plug+ins
>
> http://www.tested.com/news/how-to-automatically-tag-your-movies-with-useful-metadata/236/

**Mac**

> http://www.macupdate.com/app/mac/33814/identify

Comment: That is what my research was showing as well.  Thanks.